# How can I overclock my 8400GS to its limit without making the driver crash?

Tags: graphics-card, nvidia-geforce, overclocking

Nvidia GeForce 8400gs EVGA 512MB(It comes with a small fan)

I know this isn't the best card to overclock, but adding 200Mhz really helped me with 15+fps on a game and I was wondering if how can I keep overclocking it without making it crash? Default GPU clock is 520Mhz and 600Mhz memory as soon as it passes GPU clock of 720Mhz the driver/card crashes, but it's not overheated. I'm using EVGA Precision X 3.0.4. I really want to max this card out even it means adding a fan next to the computer and let it with a life span of 1 year or less.

Not overclocked

[image: not oc'ed]
http://gyazo.com/2652f53fdad5015fc25401c73f894409.png

Overclocked

[image: OC'ed]
http://gyazo.com/cd441c84569ad01261a66d0ba204d30b.png

Comment: The maximum is 790MHz (GPU), 920 MHz memory and 1600 shader. I have the same card. Playing NFS runs without lags in minimum settings.